# What is a nested structure in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Going over the documentation for [tf.data.Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), I see  that there is a frequent mention of "nested structures". What exactly is meant by that? Can any Python data type be considered a nested structure (e.g., `(1,3, (7,6, (0), 5))` or `dict(k=dict(3), 7, None`) or does this specifically refer to TensorFlow data types?

Comment: It generally refers to a tuple or a dict containing tensor values, or other nested structures. The typical case is a dataset where each element is a `(x, y)` pair for training, but you could also have a dict `{'x': x, 'y': y}`, or a nested tuple if you have more than one input `((x1, x2), y)`. Datasets allow you to have structures of tensors in them for convenience. See [Dataset structure](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#dataset_structure) of the guide on `tf.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing answer here from the comment section for the benefit of the community.

`Nested Structure` in `TensorFlow` generally refers to a `tuple` or a `dict` containing tensor values, or other nested structures.
 The typical case is a dataset where each element is a `(x, y)` pair for training, but you could also have a `dict {'x': x, 'y': y}`, or a nested tuple if you have more than one input `((x1, x2), y)`.
 Datasets allow you to have structures of tensors in them for convenience.
 See [Dataset structure](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#dataset_structure) of the guide on `tf.data`.

Answer (score 2):

The currently-supported types of structure are `tuple`, `dict`, and `namedtuple`.

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset:

> Common Terms: Element: A single output from calling next() on a
>   dataset iterator. Elements may be nested structures containing
>   multiple components. For example, the element (1, (3, "apple")) has
>   one tuple nested in another tuple. The components are 1, 3, and
>   "apple". Component: The leaf in the nested structure of an element.
>
> Supported types: Elements can be nested structures of tuples, named
>   tuples, and dictionaries. Element components can be of any type
>   representable by tf.TypeSpec, including tf.Tensor, tf.data.Dataset,
>   tf.SparseTensor, tf.RaggedTensor, and tf.TensorArray.